# Use of = vs .dup method

Tags: ruby

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]

array1 = array
array2 = array.dup

puts array1 == array2
```

Why do we have a `dup` method when we can just assign to another variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A statement like:

```
array1 = array
```

just assigns a *reference* to `array1` from `array`. This means that both `array` and `array1` point to the same memory location. If you change the underlying array, it will be reflected in both copies:

```
irb(main):001:0> array = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):002:0> array1 = array
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):003:0> array
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):004:0> array1
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):005:0> array[0] = 10
=> 10
irb(main):006:0> array
=> [10, 2, 3]
irb(main):007:0> array1
=> [10, 2, 3]
```

If you use `dup`, it clones the underlying data, creating new, independent storage:

```
irb(main):008:0> array2 = array.dup
=> [10, 2, 3]
irb(main):009:0> array
=> [10, 2, 3]
irb(main):010:0> array2
=> [10, 2, 3]
irb(main):011:0> array2[0] = 20
=> 20
irb(main):012:0> array
=> [10, 2, 3]
irb(main):013:0> array2
=> [20, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You're fooling yourself by:

1. Trying to reason from a single example.
2. Comparing the wrong things.

`Array` has its own [`==` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-3D-3D) that compares element by element so given:

```
a = [ 11 ]
b = [ 11 ]
```

then `a == b` is true even though `a` and `b` reference different arrays.

In general, `=` simply copies a reference similar to this in C:

```
int *i, *j;
i = j;
```

but `dup` makes a (shallow) copy.

If you compare the `object_id`s:

```
puts array1.object_id == array2.object_id
```

you'll see that the underlying array objects are different even though `==` says that the have equal contents.

Answer (score 2):

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]

array1 = array
array2 = array.dup

array << "aha"
p array1 # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "aha"]
p array2 # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```